# SQL Update a field by removing a part of it

Tags: sql, sql-update

In my work, I am stuck with a SQL problem.

I have a field in one of my table which contains strings of the form "%_abc". I want to update this column by removing "_abc" at end of every entry. Is there a nice way to get this done using SQL?

Thanks,
Anil.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
update table1 set field1 = substr(field,1,length(field1)-4) where ...
```

HTH

Comment: Thanks Zsolt and Philip, this helped. Are there functions in SQL to decaplitalize strings? for ex: SOMEFUNC("ABC DEF GHIJ") = Abc Def Ghij?

Answer (score 1):

If your database is ANSI SQL-92 compliant, you can use:

```
UPDATE myTable SET myColumn = TRIM(trailing '_abc' FROM myColumn);
```